# Can I change the template after creation of project in xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am creating an iOS article reading application which contain multiple headings,images and multiline text using platform Xcode(5.1) and chose template Empty application.
I'm in the middle of project to complete.
Now , Is it possible to change Empty application to Master Detail application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm in the middle of project to complete. Now , Is it possible to
>   change Empty application to Master Detail application

You can achieve the Master Detail application template dynamically/while running your app using **UISplitViewController**.

The `UISplitViewController` class is a container view controller that manages the presentation of two side-by-side view controllers. You use this class to implement a master-detail interface, in which the left-side view controller presents a list of items and the right-side presents details of the selected item. Split view controllers are for use exclusively on iPad devices. Attempting to create one on other devices results in an exception.

By default, the split view controller displays both of its view controllers when in a landscape orientation. However, in a portrait orientation, the split view controller displays only the detail view controller by default.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot change the template after creation of project in xcode. The only thing you have to change before the creation of project.

Answer (score 0):

The template does not restrict what can and can't be done in your app. It just sets out a boilerplate set up of your initial app.

"Changing the template" makes no sense.

The master detail template just uses a uinavigationcontroller as the main navigation. You can just add this to your storyboard.